# NodeJS Azure Storage returns 403

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, hapi.js

I have a NodeJS API which access Azure Storage. API is hosted on Windows Server 2016, IIS 10.0 with IISNode. I am using HapiJS Framework.

The API worked fine with Azure Storage Emulator, when we moved to staged environment and changed the connection string to azure storage, Azure storage returned 403,forbidden.

Below is logged information:

```
[2018-03-05T16:06:36.257Z]debug : FINAL REQUEST OPTIONS:
{ uri: 'https://some-container.blob.core.windows.net:443/images?restype=container',
method: 'HEAD',
headers: 
   { 'x-ms-client-request-id': '2e2ea0a0-208f-11e8-9345-559bff0df7cf',
 'user-agent': 'Azure-Storage/2.7.0 (NODE-VERSION v9.5.0; Windows_NT 10.0.14393)',
 'x-ms-version': '2017-04-17',
 'x-ms-date': 'Mon, 05 Mar 2018 16:06:36 GMT',
 accept: 'application/atom+xml,application/xml',
 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8',
 'content-type': '',
 'content-length': 0,
 authorization: 'SharedKey container:someKeyHere' },
mode: 'disable-fetch',
encoding: undefined,
timeout: 120000,
forever: true }

[2018-03-05T16:06:37.188Z]debug : RESPONSE:
{ error: 
   { StorageError: Forbidden
at Function.StorageServiceClient._normalizeError (C:\Load2.0\Staged\Backend\node_modules\azure-storage\lib\common\services\storageserviceclient.js:1191:23)
at BlobService.StorageServiceClient._processResponse (C:\Load2.0\Staged\Backend\node_modules\azure-storage\lib\common\services\storageserviceclient.js:738:50)
at Request.processResponseCallback [as _callback] (C:\Load2.0\Staged\Backend\node_modules\azure-storage\lib\common\services\storageserviceclient.js:311:37)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Load2.0\Staged\Backend\node_modules\azure-storage\node_modules\request\request.js:188:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:160:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Load2.0\Staged\Backend\node_modules\azure-storage\node_modules\request\request.js:1171:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:160:13)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Load2.0\Staged\Backend\node_modules\azure-storage\node_modules\request\request.js:1091:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:255:19)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:165:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
 name: 'StorageError',
 message: 'Forbidden',
 code: 'Forbidden',
 statusCode: 403,
 requestId: '2354daf1-001e-007c-25ac-b48832000000' },
  response: 
   { isSuccessful: false,
 statusCode: 403,
 body: '',
 headers: 
  { 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    server: 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
    'x-ms-request-id': '2354daf1-001e-007c-25ac-b48832000000',
    date: 'Mon, 05 Mar 2018 18:06:36 GMT' },
 md5: undefined } }
```

I do not know why I get 403, I have copied connection string from Azure Portal and double checked multiple times.

Below is the source code I am using:

```
const azureStorage = require("azure-storage");
const shortId = require("shortid");

class AzureBlobService {
    constructor(connectionString){
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
        this.blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(this.connectionString);
    }

    /**
     * Upload a file
     * @param {*} fileBuffer 
     * @param {*} filename
     * @param {*} container
     * @param {*} callback
     */
    uploadFile(fileBuffer, filename, container, callback) {
        let fileExtension = filename.slice((filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
        this.blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerToUse, err => {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, { message: "Failed to create blob container" });
            } else {
                let blobName = shortId.generate() + "." + fileExtension;
                this.blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerToUse, blobName, 
                this._bufferToStream(fileBuffer), fileBuffer.length, err => {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, { message: "Failed to upload blob" });
                } else {
                    let sasToken = this.blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(containerToUse, blobName, 
                        { AccessPolicy: { Expiry: azureStorage.date.minutesFromNow(10) } });
                        let sasUrl = this.blobService.getUrl(containerToUse, blobName, sasToken, true);

                        // TODO: return URL
                        callback(null, { url: sasUrl, blobName: blobName });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Convert a buffer to stream
     * @param {*} buffer 
     */
    _bufferToStream(buffer) {
        let stream = new Duplex();
        stream.push(buffer);
        stream.push(null);
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you copied multiple times? Are you using the correct blob storage access keys provided by the portal?

Comment: @ethane **connection string**. I have updated the typo.

Comment: Please share your code as well.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have update with the code I am using to upload

Comment: Thanks. Your code looks OK to me. Can you check the time on the server on which this code is running? Apart from incorrect key, clock skewness is another reason that could cause this 403 error.

Comment: @GauravMantri Thanks a lot, you deserve a beer. The time set on the server was different from the timezone. I synchronized with internet time and everything works fine.

Comment: Awesome! I am glad to hear that your issue is resolved. I'll take a rain check on that beer :).

Answer (score 0):

For azure-storage-node, you can create blobService object by account key or a SAS token. For example, when using storage account key generated from Azure Portal:

```
var blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey).withFilter(new azureStorage.ExponentialRetryPolicyFilter());

blobService.logger = new azureStorage.Logger();
blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('1mycontainer', function (err, res) {
  if (!err) {
    blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('1mycontainer', 'taskblob', 'task1.txt', function (error, result, response) {
      if (!error) {
          console.log("uploaded");
      } else {
          console.log(error);
      }
    }); 
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this with account key from Azure Portal and still get the same error. 403, forbidden.